# Sublime Text 3: Build System - node.js. NPM module not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, sublimetext3

I'm trying to execute node-dev in a sublime text 3 build system.  node-dev is in my path:

[image: cmd node-dev diplay]

Yet when I run this build script:

```
{
  "cmd": ["node-dev", "$file"],
  "selector": "*.js"
}
```

I get this error, which also shows that npm is in my path.

[image: npm in path img]

yet when I run with the same build script using node instead of node-dev it executes just fine.

I've also tried to include the "path" variable pointing at the node-dev bin folder, which didn't help at all.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you try updating full path of `node-dev` in cmd tag? Eg: `["c:\nodejs\bin\node-dev", "$file"]`

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sublime text docs:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html

> > **shell**

> > Optional. If true, cmd will be run through the shell (cmd.exe, `bash`…)

Try to add "shell : true

```
{
  "cmd": ["node-dev", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.js",
  "windows" : {
     "shell": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this should have been marked as answer. It solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Where is that `.sublime-build` file on Windows? It is not in `\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`

Comment: I used `"cmd": ["node", "$file"],` instead of `node-env`. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Following worked for me in Sublime Text 3 on Windows

1. Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...
2. Enter the below text in the new file
3. Save the file as "nodejs.sublime-build"

> ```
> {
>   "shell_cmd": "node ${file}",
>   "selector" : "source.js"
> }
> ```

Prerequisite is to have node.js installed

Comment: I had to use the following

    `{
      "shell_cmd": "node ${file/ /\\\\ /}",
      "selector" : "source.js"
    }`

because Sublime Text would otherwise not parse empty spaces in the filename.

Comment: Works in Linux, too

Comment: Using a bare `$file` is not recommended because as @Peteris noted, it doesn't handle spaces in file names properly. That's not a Sublime thing though; the `shell_command` is passed to the system to interpret so it's the system command processor that has a problem. Better to use `node \"$file\"` instead so that the filename is quoted for the shell (the regex also works but arguably quoting is a bit easier to interpret).

Answer (score 6):

The command is incorrect for Sublime Text 3 :)

This is one example of running node as build system:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node ${file}"
}
```

Please note that the array-version doesn't work like in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: I think you should add some [escaped] quotes around `${file}`.  If there are any spaces in the file path the command is broken. `"shell_cmd": "taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node \"${file}\""`

Comment: Actually this is the only way to make it work in Windows 10 and ST3

Answer (score 2):

For macOS, this worked for me on Sublime Text 3:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node","$file","$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector":"source.js"
}
```

#### Selector Note

My selector setting was:

```
"selector":"*.js"
```

and [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd) advised that:

> The reason is that the selector is not correct; it doesn't match file
>   names, it matches syntax scopes (i.e. it's based on the syntax in use
>   regardless of file extension); changing it to `source.js` from `*.js`
>   should get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a windows user.

Try applying the following snippet

```
{
    "selector": "source.js",
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node", "<", "$file"],
    "windows": {
        "shell": true
    }
}
```

Save this as **node.sublime-build** file.

For more info you can refer to http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/ for more.